# How to disable sorting in JQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui

I use [JQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) for sorting list items in my Django project. It works well but when in list only one item it steal sortable. User can drag and drop that one item. How to make sorting disable when there is only one item in list(#slides)?

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#slides").sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            slide_order = {};

            $("#slides").children().each(function(){
                slide_order[$(this).data('id')] = $(this).index();
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "sorting/",
                type: "post",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset= utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(slide_order)
            });
        },
    });

    $('#slides .list-group-item').click(function() {
       $("#slides").sortable("refresh");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `disabled` property of `sortable`.

If `$("#slides li")` has only one `li` than disabled sorting.

```
$("#slides").sortable({
    disabled: $("#slides li").length == 1
});
```

If you want to updated property use below

```
$('#slides .list-group-item').click(function() {
    $("#slides").sortable("refresh");
    $("#slides").sortable("option", "disabled", $("#slides li").length == 1);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
    #slides {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 60%;
    }
    
    #slides li {
      margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
      padding: 0.4em;
      padding-left: 1.5em;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      height: 18px;
    }
    
    #slides li span {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -1.3em;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      $("#slides").sortable({
        disabled: $("#slides li").length == 1
      });

      $('#slides').on('click', function() {
        $("#slides").sortable("refresh");
        $("#slides").sortable("option", "disabled", $("#slides li").length == 1);
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <ul id="slides">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s list-group-item"></span>Item 1</li>

  </ul>

  <button>add</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code works with some problems. Lets say I have one item in list and then add new item, they both became unsortable. I need refresh list i think. Do you have ideas how to make than? Check my post again pls. I update it with little code. `$("#slides").sortable("refresh");` dont work.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek check updated answer. After refresh reset `disabled` option

Comment: click event here is not correct cause user at start need double click to item. Only after that script works. I tried touch event but its dont work. `$('#slides').on('touchstart', function() { *** });` We need refresh list when user touch list item. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek Can you create fiddle with some HTML also. Or provide more detail about your issue

Comment: Finally I found solution. I put your code in my ajax script which update list. Now it works perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can get `list#slides` length and if only one item

```
listitem.addClass('unsortable');
```

and in sortable use that class with not:

```
$("#slides").sortable({
     items: "listitem:not(.unsortable)",
   // Your other code --------

    });
```